# Sending custom header in axios and retrive in backend api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have multiple frontend application, all application make request to common api. I want to set the application name in header from UI side and same application name want to retrieve it in backend api, so that I can get the from which application the request is coming. In font end side I made the changes like below.

```
 axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
 console.log("reqeust :", request)
  request.headers = {...request.headers,"appName": "Databook"}
  return request;
})
```

In java backend api side I am retriving the application name like below

```
String userAgent = request.getHeader("appName");
```

But all the api call seem to be having the cors issue

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please help me to configure this. I want to send the different frontend application name in request header and  same want to retrive it backend java api.

Comment: Make sure Axios is sending the [Access-Control-Request-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Request-Headers) HTTP header in the preflight *request*. Then, configure the Java backend to include your custom `appName` header in the [Access-Control-Allow-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers) *response* to the preflight request. You will have to tweak your CORS configuration on the server side for this.

Comment: Thanks @NikosParaskevopoulos for you inputs. It is giving cors error in my local frontend app. Will it be automatically handled in development enviroment.